# ISO time to Human readable time in python

Tags: python, datetime, epoch, strptime, strftime

I am using Python. My time format is like

```
2020-05-23T06:35:11.418279Z #May 23, 2020 at 12:05:11 PM GMT+05:30
```

I want to convert into human readable time like

```
23-05-2020 12:05 PM
```

I tried parser too. But no effect.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Comment: ISO time is perfectly human readable. Your problem, however, is that you want to convert timezone to GMT+5. For that, I suggest using `pytz` module.

Comment: I have tried  using dateutil.parser

Comment: @Błotosmętek But I don't want to show T and milliseconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime, pytz
isodate = '2020-05-23T06:35:11.418279Z'
d = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(isodate[:-1]).replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc) # we need to strip 'Z' before parsing
print(d.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')).strftime('%d-%m-%Y %I:%M %p'))
```

Comment: It is perfectly working fine dood.Thanks you so much.But what is it mean isodate[:-1]

Comment: `isodate[:-1]` is `isodate` without the last character (which is Z, which does not conform to strict ISO format)

Comment: I have one more doubt.Don't mistaken me.Because these time stuffs are so much confusing me. We are adding timezonr('Asia/Kolkata').What If suppose my customers are from america or europe.

Comment: Then use appriopriate time zone. You wanted `GMT+05:30`, that's India time. You can check the list of available timezone names by `print(pytz.all_timezones)`

Answer (score 5):

See also [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/127803/10197418)

Unfortunately, a string as '2020-05-23T06:35:11.418279Z' cannot be parsed directly with the [built-in `fromisoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) (Python 3.7+) due to the `Z`. You can use `strptime` instead, or [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62769371/10197418), or dateutil's parser. Ex:

```
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil

s = '2020-05-23T06:35:11.418279Z'

### parsing options
# strptime
dt = datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
# alternatively fromisoformat with replace (most efficient)
dt = datetime.fromisoformat(s.replace('Z', '+00:00'))
# or more convenient and a bit less efficient:
dt = dateutil.parser.isoparse(s)

# change timezone to Indian Standard Time:
dt = dt.astimezone(dateutil.tz.gettz('Asia/Kolkata'))
# datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 23, 12, 5, 11, 418279, tzinfo=tzfile('Asia/Calcutta'))

# note for Python 3.9+:
# use zoneinfo from the standard lib to get timezone objects

# now format to string with desired format
s_out = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p')
s_out
# '2020-05-23 12:05 PM'
```

Comment: That should be `%I` instead of `%H` to get 12-hour clock.

Comment: To get 24-hour clock, use `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M` for `strftime`