# want to convert json timestamp into normal timestamp (CST Hrs) in python

Tags: python, json

I am downloading a json file containing timestamp using python . But the timestamp i am getting is below format

```
 `2021-04-01T21:43:52.757Z`
```

Want to convert into normal timestamp (CST Hrs). I also see that the time is increased by 4 hours when i compare the report manually.

```
 `4/1/2021  5:43:53 PM`
```

The above hours is 4 hrs less when i compare with json file entry. Please advise me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ISO time to Human readable time in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61969589/iso-time-to-human-readable-time-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use python's `datetime` module to handle this. The `Z` in the string actually means time zone 0 or UTC time which is 6 hours ahead of CST not 4:

```
import datetime

date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(
    "2021-04-01T21:43:52.757Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"
)

date_object = date_object - datetime.timedelta(hours=6)

print(
    f"{date_object.month}/{date_object.day}/{date_object.year} {date_object.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')}"
)
```

Which will give this output:

```
4/1/2021 03:43:52 PM
```

have to use an f string if you want non zero padded dates because its not available in `datetime` according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

You can use `pytz` module to deal with time zones directly and not hardcode them if you want. Or if you are on python 3.9 you can use [`timezone`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timezone-objects) objects to create timezones yourself